# Comment différencier ces synonymes de "saillie" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, synonymes, connotation, définition

En français, il existe plusieurs substantifs exprimant plus ou moins la même idée, l'antonyme de *trou* : *renflement*, *saillie*, *bosse*, *protubérance*, *élévation*, (*pro*)*éminence*. Tous ces mots sont-ils des synonymes parfaits ? Et si ce n'est pas le cas, comment les distinguer ? Les dictionnaires semblent employer des définitions circulaires, ce qui ne fait que compliquer les choses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non, aucun de ces mots n'est un synonyme parfait de l'un des autres, même si bien sûr il y a un recouvrement de certains sens.

- ***Saillie*** a plusieurs sens distincts, l'antonyme de trou n'étant pas le plus courant.

Pour signifier cet antonyme et suivant de quoi on veut parler, certains mots seront privilégiés, voire quasiment exclusivement utilisés :

- *Je me suis fait une **bosse** sur le front en me cognant.* Impossible d'utiliser autre chose.
- ***Renflement*** suppose qu'à l'origine, il n'était pas présent.
- ***Protubérance*** est un terme plus technique, ne s'emploie guère s'il ne s'agit pas de quelque chose de significatif.
- ***Élévation*** est le plus souvent utilisé pour signifier autre chose. Quand il s'agit de celle attendue, elle ne peut être dirigée que vers le haut.
- ***Éminence*** ne s'emploie plus aujourd'hui qu'au sens figuré.
- ***Proéminence*** est un terme plutôt technique et comme *protubérance* ne s'applique que si la chose en question est clairement visible.

Comment: Dirais-tu que l'ensemble est plus topographique ou anatomique ?

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse L'ensemble est disparate mais certains termes sont plus l'un (élévation, proéminence) ou l'autre (renflement, protubérance). *Bosse* est familier. *Saillie* peut concerner l'architecture, la conversation ou la reproduction...